# Export Request_Response of HttpInstrumentation to DB

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, open-telemetry, appinsights

In my asp.net core app, using Opentelemetry and exporting it to AppInsights.
Due to GDPR,instead of exporting the API request_response with Data to AppInsights I would like to add it to DB.

Any Solution, how can we do that?

Comment: I suggest you could try to use some log tool like serilog or else to log the request response data to db by developing the codes by yourself.

Comment: yes. I think so too. CustomExporter to dump the data in DB